# AttributeError: 'BlockBlobService' object has no attribute 'create_block_blob_from_path'

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

Accocrding [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/) manual I shoud use thise pice of code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings
block_blob_service.create_block_blob_from_path(
    'mycontainer',
    'myblockblob',
    'sunset.png',
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')
            )
```

But got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'BlockBlobService' object has no attribute 'create_block_blob_from_path'
```

Tried from `git`, as well as from `pip`

```
pip install azure-storage
```

Comment: Where are you creating `block_blob_service` in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the tutorial is out of date, compared with the latest Python SDK. I don't think there's a `create_block_blob_from_path` anymore - I looked at the sdk code ([here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py)). There are separate imports for block blobs and page blobs, with the method being `create_blob_from_path`.

So with a simple correction:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.file import ContentSettings
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name="<storagename>",account_key="<storagekey>")

content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type = "image/png")
blob_service.create_blob_from_path("mycontainer","myblockblob","sunset.png",content_settings)
```

Comment: any update for how this is done with the newest update 24 days ago?

Comment: @M.Smith - I know of no breaking changes.